# Django template tags on base.html

Tags: django

I have a base page and some templates with views:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="userpanel"> 
      user panel
   </div>
   <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}some title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
some content
{% endblock %}
```

I want to add user panel on base page. Can I somehow use there template tags like if/for?
I would like to be able to use something like:

```
{% if user.admin}
admin panel
{% endif %}

{% if user.moderator}
moderator panel
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you clarify? It looks like your user panel is on the base page. What is it you want to change?

Comment: Yes you can use `{% if %}` and `{% for %}` tags in your base template.

Comment: and how can I set context for base? i mean-some info if user is signed etc

Comment: the context you apply to the child template should be applied to the parent template, try it

Comment: Can I somehow pass some values to all templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context variable always has the request.user (the current user).

So you can do:
if request.user.is_superuser ...
And:
If request.user.is_staff ....

Both vars you can assign in the Admin.auth.user.

Your second question regarding to make an assignment tag, see: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
# app/templatetags/mytags.py
@register.assignment_tag
def get_messages_list_for_user(user):
    list = Messages.objects.filter(owner=user)
    return list
```

Then in the template you go:

```
# base.html
{% load mytags %}
{% for m in get_messages_list_for_user request.user %}
{{ m.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

You always have the request user so you can put it in one template or in your base template.

Comment: But what if I want to check on every template if there are some unread messages?

Comment: Make an assignment tag that returns the list of messages. You can include that assignment in the base template. This is how template tags can make your site really good. Did I answer your question?

Comment: How can I make this tag? Some example?

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your follow up question. Good coding.